# Copy null data to not null in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy the data in some old columns to some newly created columns, in the same table. Some columns are `bit` and some are `text` (old) to `varchar` (new). The difficulty I'm running into is that the old columns have some null data in them, whereas the new columns are `not null`. How can I make it so that if the old data is null, then the new data gets a not null value, either 0 or '', depending.

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    update tblProject
        set
            NewBitColumn1 = OldBitColumn1,
            NewBitColumn2 = OldBitColumn2,
            NewBitColumn3 = OldBitColumn3,

            NewVarCharColumn1 = OldTextColumn1,
            NewVarCharColumn2 = OldTextColumn2,
            NewVarCharColumn3 = OldTextColumn3,

        COMMIT TRAN -- Transaction Success
    END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN --RollBack in case of Error

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
END CATCH
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: More important, don't do that!!! Keep the null values!!! Storing fake nulls is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
update tblProject
    set
        NewBitColumn1 = coalesce(OldBitColumn1, 0),
        NewBitColumn2 = coalesce(OldBitColumn2, 0),
        NewBitColumn3 = coalesce(OldBitColumn3, 0),

        NewVarCharColumn1 = coalesce(OldTextColumn1, ''),
        NewVarCharColumn2 = coalesce(OldTextColumn2, ''),
        NewVarCharColumn3 = coalesce(OldTextColumn3, '');
```